# Xcode 6: No provisioning profiles found for AdHoc distribution build; after healthkit entitlements added

Tags: xcode, xcode6, provisioning, ipa

I updated to Xcode 6's final release last week, and all as gone well.  I've been able to build my code, generate adhoc distribution builds (for legacy Testflight), etc.

Today I added some healthkit code, and had to enable HealthKit in the AppId to do the full build.  After I did this, Xcode is refusing to Distribute the build I've just archived to create the final .ipa file.  I get the error below no matter what now.

What I've done to try to fix this, as various tests:

- regenerated my apps Distribution provisioning profile for adhoc release.
- deleted all previous Xcode provisioning profiles, reinstalled and reimported all the provisioning profiles.  The updated profile is present for sure.
- changed the Team in the General settings, and changed it back to the correct one; allowed Xcode to try to "Fix" the issue.
- Updated "build settings" to have the correct Distribution provisioning profile for Release, which Archives use.  Confirmed code signing is correct for the Team
- Tried "Automatic" for provisioning profile and code signing, as an alternate.
- close and restart Xcode

None of this has helped generate the .ipa again, which worked before adding Healthkit support and invaliding all this.

How am I supposed to fix this to properly generate my ipa builds again?

**EDIT**
I was able to get an IPA built by installing an XC generated provisioning profile that appears to match my Distribution Adhoc profile entirely, except that it includes ALL the user devices I have in the portal, including ones that have long since been phased out (ex-employees).  The only difference is the desired profile excludes about half the devices.  I'd prefer not to have to do this.

[image]

Comment: I have a similar issue: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248835?tstart=0

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing more or less similar problems since i started using XCode6. Before XC6, i could use my ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile that was linked to a limited number of devices to create an ad-hoc distribution.

Since XC6, I get the same error message as above, while at the same time Xcode generates its own XC Ad-hoc provisioning profile. From that moment on, when you try again,this XC generated profile is always used and you don't get the error anymore. But of course, at that moment it is using a profile that links to all my registered devices, which i do not want.
No matter what i have tried, eg removing all profiles, it keeps on generating and using that XC generated profile that links to all registered devices.

It gets worse: as a workaround, i tried to modify the XC generated profile and simply remove the devices i don't want. After refreshing in XCode and creating an adhoc distribution, I get the same error again stating that no profiles can be found. Again Xcode generates its own XC-adhoc profile, which of course already existed, and again all devices are linked back to that XC-adhoc profile...

FYI: i don't use anything like Healthkit or so, just default features.

Strictly speaking, it is not blocking from creating an adhoc distribution, but also in my case I have registered devices which belong to different customers, which means i prefer to limit the number of devices for a particular adhoc distribution.

Comment: I have the same problem with XC6

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable HealthKit in the apple developer portal in the app id and update your provision profile?

You need to activate that, and update your provision profile.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what caused this over what used to work fine.  I added the feature to the App ID on the portal, after which the provisioning profiles were marked "Invalid" in that portal.  I regenerated them, and they were corrected.  I reinstalled the new versions.